# In awe of difficult times/hardship?

Tags: word-usage

In awe of difficult times. Is this correct ? 
i know that in awe of is an expression of admiration and respect but can it include difficult times?

If not what is the word for expressing the feeling of being helpless infront of something and respecting it.

Comment: Welcome to SE! Could you add more context, like a complete sentence? Appropriate use of many English terms depends on context. [How to Ask](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Like for example, In awe of difficult times, i choose to remain silent.

Comment: Grammatically you might get away with that but no native listener would accept "In awe of difficult times/hardship" as half-way idiomatic.

Even if’ you’d Posted any research, being helpless in front of and respecting  something would be different concepts and “awe” would work for neither.

Can you Post at least two different examples of what you actually want to say?

Answer (score 1):

Can it (the word '**awe**') be included in describing difficult times?

From [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/awe):

> ​a feeling of great respect, usually mixed with fear or surprise

As in:

> I was too much in awe of him to address him directly.

and

> Too much in awe of his father to make him a confidant, he wrestled in
>   the gloomy solitude of his own mind.

Yes, one can be *in awe* or *awestruck* in difficult times.  Awesome: from 17th century church use meaning “profoundly reverential" to later meaning “inspiring awe", now we have a word meaning a feeling of great respect, usually mixed with fear or surprise:

Answer (score -2):

"In awe of difficult times" sounds weird. Although "in awe of" means "great respect", it doesn't gel with "difficult times". Apprehension or dread are more appropriate in this context.